# Multiple detail views in master-detail application. How should I approach this?

Tags: ios, swift, master-detail

I'm pretty new with app development and am experimenting with a master-detail app using Swift.
I have a master `UITableview` that I have successfully populated with an array of data (i.e. not static cells) and now I am ready to design the detail pages for each of the 100 or so items in the master tableview.
Each detail page will have its own unique combination of text and images, and in my mind there are two approaches I can take.

1. The first is to add a static view controller and segue for each item in the master tableview.
2. The second is to use a single detail page and change the content of that page depending on which item in the master tableview was selected.

> Can anyone comment on these approaches and make any recommendations regarding which approach to take?
>   Are there any performance benefits/detriments of using one approach over the other? Would having multiple static detail pages make a significant difference to the overall size of the app?

There seems to be less thinking involved if I used multiple detail pages, but the single view controller approach would be much easier to manage and add to in the future.

Comment: Second approach is the best approach if you want to show details of items  from master tableview which contains more than 100 cells.Use static cell connections only if you have limited cells and also each detail page contains completely different functionality rather than just vary in text and images.

Comment: What you mean for "will have its own unique combination of text and images"? You mean that different data will show up in every Child controller or that you also want every child to have its own layout?